# Creating transparent svg element with background image

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I am trying to implement upload container **similar** to [this tutorial](https://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CustomFileInputs/). I have a svg element, which represents an icon and image as background. I don't know how to achieve this result and make svg element transparent:

[image]

```css
figure {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #fff;
    display: block;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 0 auto 0px;
    position: relative;
    top: 50px;
}
svg {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.upload-image-drop {
    background: url('http://via.placeholder.com/200x200');
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: rgb(102, 102, 102);
    border-style: solid;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="upload-image-drop" aria-disabled="false" style="height: 200px; border-style: none; border-radius: 0px;">
   <figure>
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="17" viewBox="0 0 20 17">
         <path d="M10 0l-5.2 4.9h3.3v5.1h3.8v-5.1h3.3l-5.2-4.9zm9.3 11.5l-3.2-2.1h-2l3.4 2.6h-3.5c-.1 0-.2.1-.2.1l-.8 2.3h-6l-.8-2.2c-.1-.1-.1-.2-.2-.2h-3.6l3.4-2.6h-2l-3.2 2.1c-.4.3-.7 1-.6 1.5l.6 3.1c.1.5.7.9 1.2.9h16.3c.6 0 1.1-.4 1.3-.9l.6-3.1c.1-.5-.2-1.2-.7-1.5z"></path>
      </svg>
   </figure>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9p6w20fw/)

Answer (score 0):

It look in this tutorial he's painting the icon with this property . `fill:#fff;` so..:

```
svg {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    fill:rgb(102, 102, 102);
}
```

Comment: Please, look at the image in my question

Comment: @Matt if do you want it transparent (I'm not sure if in the image it is) you should make a group, let me search something

Comment: @Matt Well matt, i'm not sure if what you want is possible or may be I don't know the way. The only thing that I could think is, the svg should be a circle with this 'icon' inside in transparent, and fill it in white.  Any way, I suggest you to take a look in this library that may could help you snap-svg.js

Comment: Yes, that's why I am asking here :D I am not such experienced front-end dev.